# Upgrade Android app and keep old SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, upgrade

I'm writting a small app for gym exercises. I keep my records in SQLiteDatabase and I want this app to start running as fast as I finish main part of the app. But further I want to develop this app and add some more features. There will be some records in a database yet. How can I save this records and move it to new version of the app? I'm developing with Android Studio, and each run app is installed from the scratch(before previous version is unistalled and all data is deleted?) if there were any changes, right? So, how can I keep old records and add them to new version app? I have seen some answers with onUpgrade, but it wasn't that specific that i can understand them, beacause they don't tell anything about upgrading only app, not the databse. And sorry for my English :)

Comment: Pressing run from android studio will not overwrite the database. It doesn't install from scratch, only updates the apk.

Comment: Ok, and what will happen, if someone has app installed, and he will install new version from .apk? Will the database be removed?

Comment: Not if he updates it. As opposed to uninstalling then reinstalling.

Comment: Updating = install from .apk when there is app already installed or I have to handle some specific method to say that this update, not new instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing a new version of your app doesn't necessarily remove its data (unless you uninstall it manually before installation or just clear data manually).

Also, if you change your database structure in an update, you can override 
[*SQLiteOpenHelper*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)'s [*onUpgrade*](http://goo.gl/Eqlyxj) method in order to handle database updates properly.

Comment: Ok, and the only way to store data even someone unistall the app is to store that data on a server?

Comment: @meDarq yes, I think that's the best option. You can also store it in device's external storage, but I'd not recommend that.