# How to limit an Android app to thousands of specific devices

Tags: android, gmail, google-play

This is a bit specific but let's say :

I just got a thousand of tablets. I want to install my app on these ones only.

I want nobody else to have the app and I want updates to be as smooth as possible.

I would also like to avoid using a third party server as it's more work and it might not even be possible (I don't think there's an Android permission allowing to delete and install apps on a device).

Is there a faster way than manually creating a gmail adress for every single one of them and restrict publishing to a google+ group that all these accounts are subscribed to ?

Is there any kind of script or option to have this done ? My googling was resultless so far.

In short how to manage update for a single purpose app ?

EDIT : I've found this : https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html#locktask
but no update feature is mentionned

EDIT 2 : I believe it is a pertinent question as it's unanswered here : [Update Android app in COSU device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102586/update-android-app-in-cosu-device)

EDIT 3 : I've found the "google private channel" but it doesn't seem to quite answer the problematics I face yet

Comment: May I have a feedback on what's wrong with my question so I can fix it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to login with your publisher account and

1. open publish apk deshboard.
2. Click on See List.
   [image]
3. One Pop up will open and you can restrict the device from there.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I actually want to limit it to a pool of devices not a brand or a model. I want my app to be installed on the 1000 tablets I just bought and them only.

Comment: I think it is not possible to restrict as you want in Google Play Store Console, But you can do one thing create beta tester 1000, they can only see your application. It might help this. I am not sure. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Too fastidious. Also 1 user can only have 10 devices at max, so I would have to create a lot of users.